# Content goes outside div

Tags: html, css, css-float, overflow, positioning

As the title implies my problem is that the content doesn't stay inside the main container (no floats are used).

Yes, I know there are a lot of questions regarding this matter here on Stack, though none of the solutions I've tried works for me.

What I've tried:

- Overflow: hidden on "#infoBox"
- A div with "clear:both" as the last node in "#infoBox"
- position: relative in the CSS of '#infoBox'

**HTML:**

```
<div id="infoBox">
    <div id="statsDiv">
        <div id="nrOfCrimes">
            <div id="nrOfCrimesGraphDiv">
                //... code for jQuery Visualize (graphs)
            </div>
            <ul>
                //... li's ...
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="crimesPerMonth">
            <div id="crimesPerMonthGraphDiv">
                //... code for jQuery Visualize (graphs)
            </div>
            <ul>
                //... li's ...
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#infoBox {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  width: 89%;
  background: #fbfbf7;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

#nrOfCrimesGraphDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: 300px;
}

#crimesPerMonthGraphDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: -80px;
  left: 300px;
}
```

**Note:** No CSS is specified for "#statsDiv", "#nrOfCrimes" and "#crimesPerMonth".

As you can see on this image the elements floats outside the main container:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your graph divs are positioned absolutely inside a div with static positioning. What you probably want is to add position:relative to your #infoBox rule. That will cause the absolute positioning to take effect within the #infoBox bounding box, not an outer one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tried to add position: relative to #infoBox but still the same. :/

Comment: There are a bunch of approaches you could take - hard to say without seeing the full extend of the document and rules, but it is pretty weird that you'd need to absolutely position those divs, especially with negative top and left values. You should probably be able to accomplish what you want with statically positioned divs inside the #infoBox and adding margins and/or padding (and/or overflow set to auto or hidden), depending on how you want them to lay out. It's hard to tell what the visual goal is here.

Answer (score 2):

Absolute positioning removes an element from the layout - so the parent container no longer knows how big the element is (or even where it is).

You either have to manually set the size of the container to compensate for this, or use floats. If you do use floats, be sure to clear your floats to allow the normal document flow to continue.